# Asp.net itextsharp issue with row's text close to bottomline

Tags: asp.net, itext

[image: Pdf table][image: Image for table in pdf]I am working on generating pdf using itextsharp ,In my table i have multiple columns such as sr.ni. name .],quantity ,mrp ,price tax etc.

Name column has round about 40% of total width all values in other column comes right in middle of row but name's value is somehow close to bottom line ,Everything is same for all columns ie. style,font etc.

```
code
                            var cell=new PdfPcell();
                            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(price, font));
                            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                            cell.VerticleAlignMent= Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                            producttable.AddCell(cell);
```

same code for all values

any solutions.

also tried

```
           cell.AddElement(new Chunk(name, font));
                    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                    productsTable.AddCell(cell);
```

didnt work

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Show us what you mean (a picture and some code are worth a thousand words).

Comment: 5.1.2.0 is the version

Comment: That's old, but not that old. Show us some code and a screen shot please.

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce that. Note that you didn't literally copy/paste your code. `VerticleAlignMent` doesn't exist and `ALIGN_CENTER` isn't a valid value for `VerticalAlignment`; see the answer you received on this question. I'm pretty sure there's a difference somewhere. Can you show your *actual* code.

Comment: Yes bruno i didnt copy pasted that one line of verticle

Answer (score 1):

You can assign vertical alignment to your particular cell as shown below:

```
        pdfCell2.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM;
        pdfCell3.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        pdfCell4.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP;
```